# Wedge product of vector fields

Tags: vector-analysis, exterior-algebra

Can somebody explain me step by step how can I compute the *wedge product* $X\wedge Y$ of two vector fields, $X,Y$, in $\mathbb{C}^2$?

We can consider
$$
X=X_1\partial_x+X_2\partial_y
$$
and
$$
Y=Y_1\partial_x+Y_2\partial_y
$$

Please!

Comment: I take it $x$ and $y$ are complex coordinates?

Comment: Yes @Muphrid they are complex

Answer (score 2):

Expand out.  $ \ \ e_i \wedge e_i=0, \ \ e_i \wedge e_j=-e_j \wedge e_i$

$e_1=\partial_x, e_2=\partial_y
\\X\wedge Y=X_1Y_1e_1\wedge e_1+X_1Y_2e_1\wedge e_2+X_2Y_1e_2\wedge e_1+X_2Y_2e_2\wedge e_2\\
=(X_1Y_2-X_2Y_1)e_1\wedge e_2=(X_1Y_2-X_2Y_1) \partial_x \wedge \partial_y$

Comment: What does the objecct $\partial_x\wedge\partial_y$ means?

Comment: see [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form]